# Symfony2 translation in templates does not apply

Tags: symfony, translation

I have this in my twig template:

```
{% trans %}lala{% endtrans %}
{{ 'Presentation'|trans|raw }}
and lots of not translatable twig html in between.
```

And the only way it applies translations is when in the controller action I call the translator:

```
$t = $this->get('translator')->trans('lala');
```

If I comment the line above, the translation does not occur. How can I force that? (Well, what am I doing wrong?)

For more info, this is my config.yml file:

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

And I get the locale variable through my routing:

```
my_bundle_name:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/add
    requirements:
        _locale: en|ja
```

EDIT:
The files are located like a normal symfony project.
my twig template is located in:

```
src/COMP/myBundle/Resources/views/entity1/new.twig.html
```

The only difference might be that it extends a base template which is located in

```
src/COMP/myBundle/Resources/views/base.html.twig
```

The translation are also located in the Resources folder:

```
src/COMP/myBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.xlf
src/COMP/myBundle/Resources/translations/messages.ja.xlf
src/COMP/myBundle/Resources/translations/validators.ja.xlf
```

the controller is also located in the default place:

```
src/COMP/myBundle/Controller/myentitycontroller.php
```

I've been keeping developing with that trick, to explicitly call the translator, and now it suddenly works even without that workaround. And I am unable to repeat the same beheaviour as before.

I am still curious of why was that happening to me, but maybe I should delete the question...

My first guess is that I was trying to translate a template which was a "partial". I mean, from base.html.twig I was calling an action of a controller:

```
{{ render(controller('COMPMyBundle:Default:Welcome', {'aprequest': app.request})) }}
```

But I am unable to repeat the same beheaviour. (Before, when that was happening to me, and now, when I am trying to get the same beheaviour, I cleared the cache several times, so it shouldn't be that).

Comment: Where is the twig template situated in your project? And the controller? And the translations files?

Comment: @cheesemacfly you can look at the edit. Anyway, I've been keeping with the developing and now suddenly it works without the trick, and I am unable to repeat the beheaviour. (Should I delete the question?).

Comment: I have the same kind of project structure (except my `base.html.twig` is in the `app/Resources/views` folder) so I don't see any problem with that...I think you can leave the question open at least for few days in case you see the behavior again!